# Passing an array as parameter on update_batch codeigniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

I want to pass array as a parameter to model. I little confuse, how to pass them.

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function update_json_detail() {
    $post_data = $this->input->post("POST_ARRAY");
    $execute = array();
    foreach ($post_data as $data) {
        $execute[] = array(
            'ID'=> $data['0'],
            'MATERIAL' => $data['7'],
            'AC' => $data['8']
        );
    }

    print_r($execute);
    /* CODE TO INSERT BATCH */
    $callback = $this->m_admin->update_eir_to_cost($execute);
}
```

To debug it, this is the result of those array

```
[{"ID":"68","MATERIAL":"Test","AC":"a"},     {"ID":"69","MATERIAL":"b","AC":"c"}]
```

This is the **MODEL**

```
public function update_eir_to_cost($id, $material, $ac) {
    $data = array(
        "MATERIAL" => $material,
        "AC" => $ac
    );

    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->where($id);
    $this->db->update_batch('tb_repair_detail', $data);
    $this->db->trans_complete();

    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
        // generate an error... or use the log_message() function to log your error
        echo "Error Updating";
    }
}
```

My case is, I want to use update_batch to update my table.

> Actually, update material and AC where ID = ID

Any help it so appreciated.

Comment: parameter are not matching of model and could print the data in $post_data and post you need to convert it into array to use update_batch function

Answer (score 0):

The result you shown up for `print_r($execute)` is not correct. That should be the rerult for `json_encode($execute)`. Here is the result for `print_r($execute)`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 68
            [MATERIAL] => Test
            [AC] => b
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 69
            [MATERIAL] => a
            [AC] => c
        )
)
```

Now, in your model

```
public function update_eir_to_cost($data) {
  $this->db->update_batch('tb_repair_detail', $data, 'ID');
  // Produces: 
  // UPDATE `tb_repair_detail` SET `MATERIAL` = CASE
  // WHEN `ID` = '68' THEN 'Test'
  // WHEN `ID` = '69' THEN 'b'
  // ELSE `name` END,
  // `AC` = CASE 
  // WHEN `ID` = '68' THEN 'a'
  // WHEN `ID` = '69' THEN 'c'
  // ELSE `AC` END
  // WHERE `ID` IN ('68','69')
}
```

Have a look at [Updating Data](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update)